# Stopping and Starting Apache Using PHP (!)

Tags: php, apache, batch-file, wampserver

I have two problems which are related.

1) I have a batch file that contains this:

```
net stop wampapache
net start wampapache
```

Which tries to stop and start my wamp server. When I double click the `stop.bat` file with the above it works successfully. When I try to run that from my PHP script, it stops the server but doesn't start it fully which I am guessing is because Apache is waiting for that PHP process to exit?

```
function php_kill(){

    exec('stop.bat', $output = array(), $return);

    return $return;

}
```

2) Is there a way to restart my webserver (apache) whilst keeping session variables that PHP needs available?

Thanks all

Comment: Not sure but guessing: if its waiting to end, could you not `exit($return)` at the end of you function? or store the vars inside a database, as soon as you need them do a check in your index to see if the specific entry exists.

Comment: I'm not sure as well, but I think it's because 'exec' waits for the process to end, but the process actually kills PHP so the whole thing gets stuck! Idea: running 'stop.bat' as a background process?

Comment: Davide - that's a good idea, maybe I can add a two second pause before I perform the stop/start of Apache.

Comment: Abs, I'm not aware of methods to run a background process on Windows, but I found this link http://www.somacon.com/p395.php
Hope it helps.

Comment: Davide - I am using your solution. Do you think you can outline it and then add that link so i can select as correct answer so someone else can benefit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that `exec` waits for the process to end, but the process actually kills PHP so the whole thing gets stuck.

Running `stop.bat` as a background process should fix it. (here [how to run a background process on Windows](http://www.somacon.com/p395.php))

Comment: Thank you Davide. I made use of `WScript.Shell` - this is only a windows solution and its what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP process is killing a process that, in turn, kills the PHP process. It's like going back in time and murdering your parents before they gave birth to you. I don't see how it can work.

One has to ask why this functionality is necessary. If you must do it this way, you should look into scheduling a service restart from the script. I don't know if this is possible via PHP and Windows.

Comment: I thought the batch script will execute and stop and start apache. I just need that PHP script to die as soon as its tried to be stoped. Is there something that is opposite to `ignore_user_abort` for a process?!?